# Issue w/Plymouth booting on new hard disk

Tags: ubuntu, boot, plymouth

Alright so I am having a laptop issue & my one is in the shop getting on 7 weeks now, so a couple weeks back I bought a cheap one from a pawnbrokers & that crashed after the first update that it attempted. So I have an old pen drive w/a copy of Ubuntu 15.04 from years ago that I tried to install, so I could have a functioning laptop. Anyway that did not work & I kinda sussed that was due to a faulty hard drive so I got a new one for cheap & plugged that in. For this new hard drive I am too cheap to want to buy the windows key, especially for a laptop that's cheap & old, so I am back to trying to install Linux.

So I trialled it & immediately run into an issue w/a password that isn't set up because this is the first time the laptop is starting w/a fresh hard disk. So whatever, I reboot it & try again to install it. Now I am running into the issue of it failing to install because

```
systemct1 status plymouth-start.service
```

So I looked into the Plymouth start service & why I might be having this problem. Apparently it is the function responsible for starting up and shutting down Linux. Apparently a reason I might be having this is another OS on this computer that hasn't shut down correctly.

I am not sure what to make of this, does anyone have an answer for me?